# Simple pair/vector2 utility class for c++20

Tags: c++, c++20

I have rewritten the Vector2 class that I usually use in my projects. The code looks as follows:

```
#pragma once

#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

namespace ae
{
    // Does T support constexpr?
    template <Literal T>
    concept Literal = std::is_fundamental_v<T>;

    template <Literal T>
    class Vector2
    {
    public:
        constexpr Vector2() noexcept :
        x(T{}),
        y(T{})
        {}

        constexpr Vector2(T x, T y) noexcept :
        x(x),
        y(y)
        {}

        constexpr Vector2(const Vector2<T>& other) noexcept :
        x(other.x),
        y(other.y)
        {}

        constexpr Vector2(const Vector2<T>&& other) noexcept :
        x(std::move(other.x)),
        y(std::move(other.y))
        {}

        constexpr void operator =(const Vector2<T>& rhs) noexcept
        {
            this->x = rhs.x;
            this->y = rhs.y;
        }

        template <Literal T>
        constexpr void operator =(const Vector2<T>&& rhs) noexcept
        {
            this->x = std::move(rhs.x);
            this->y = std::move(rhs.y);
        }

        T x;
        T y;
    };

    template <Literal T>
    [[nodiscard]] constexpr Vector2<T> operator -(const Vector2<T>& rhs) noexcept
    {
        return { -rhs.x, -rhs.y };
    }

    template <Literal T>
    [[nodiscard]] constexpr Vector2<T>& operator +=(Vector2<T>& lhs, const Vector2<T>& rhs) noexcept
    {
        lhs.x += rhs.x;
        lhs.y += rhs.y;

        return lhs;
    }

    template <Literal T>
    [[nodiscard]] constexpr Vector2<T>& operator -=(Vector2<T>& lhs, const Vector2<T>& rhs) noexcept
    {
        lhs.x -= rhs.x;
        lhs.y -= rhs.y;

        return lhs;
    }

    template <Literal T>
    [[nodiscard]] constexpr Vector2<T> operator +(const Vector2<T>& lhs, const Vector2<T>& rhs) noexcept
    {
        return { lhs.x + rhs.x, lhs.y + rhs.y };
    }

    template <Literal T>
    [[nodiscard]] constexpr Vector2<T> operator -(const Vector2<T>& lhs, const Vector2<T>& rhs) noexcept
    {
        return { lhs.x - rhs.x, lhs.y - rhs.y };
    }

    template <Literal T>
    [[nodiscard]] constexpr Vector2<T> operator *(const Vector2<T>& lhs, T rhs) noexcept
    {
        return { lhs.x * rhs, lhs.y * rhs };
    }

    template <Literal T>
    [[nodiscard]] constexpr Vector2<T> operator *(T lhs, const Vector2<T>& rhs) noexcept
    {
        return { rhs.x * lhs, rhs.y * lhs };
    }

    template <Literal T>
    [[nodiscard]] constexpr Vector2<T>& operator *=(Vector2<T>& lhs, T rhs) noexcept
    {
        lhs.x *= rhs;
        lhs.y *= rhs;

        return lhs;
    }

    template <Literal T>
    [[nodiscard]] constexpr Vector2<T> operator /(const Vector2<T>& lhs, T rhs) noexcept
    {
        return { lhs.x / rhs, lhs.y / rhs };
    }

    template <Literal T>
    [[nodiscard]] constexpr Vector2<T>& operator /=(Vector2<T>& lhs, T rhs) noexcept
    {
        lhs.x /= rhs;
        lhs.y /= rhs;

        return lhs;
    }

    template <Literal T>
    [[nodiscard]] constexpr bool operator ==(const Vector2<T>& lhs, const Vector2<T>& rhs) noexcept
    {
        return (lhs.x == rhs.x) && (lhs.y == rhs.y);
    }

    template <Literal T>
    [[nodiscard]] constexpr bool operator !=(const Vector2<T>& lhs, const Vector2<T>& rhs) noexcept
    {
        return (lhs.x != rhs.x) || (lhs.y != rhs.y);
    }

    template <Literal T>
    std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& os, const Vector2<T>& rhs) noexcept
    {
        return os << "{" << rhs.x << ", " << rhs.y << "}";
    }
}
```

Looking for any feedback, perhaps especially style wise. Note that the class does not represent a 'mathematical vector' just a 2d coordinate / pair.

I have a Vector3 and Vector4 class as well, so any improvements that apply here, should also apply there.

Comment: Why do you have `[[nodiscard]]` on your compound assignment operators (`+=`, `-=`, etc.)?  Those are often used for the side effect and ignore the returned value.

Comment: That is a mistake. I copy pasted the declartions and edited the names afterwards. Thank you for pointing it out :P.

Answer (score 3):

```
// Does T support constexpr?
template <Literal T>
concept Literal = std::is_fundamental_v<T>;
```

I see what you're going for.  This isn't bad, but imagine someone tries to make a Vector2 with a custom type... they'll have to find this comment to understand why compilation failed.  If you just use `typename T` and get rid of the concept, then the compiler will show a traceback and say "T is not constexpr" which is a lot more helpful to the user.  TL;DR: I'd get rid of this concept.

---

This is a lot of constructors.  Is there any reason not to use the default ones?

---

Can you leverage `std::pair` to define the constructors/the comparison operators for you?  Maybe you can inherit from it?

---

```
constexpr Vector2<T> operator *(const Vector2<T>& lhs, T rhs)
```

This has the same semantics as converting `rhs` into `Vector2<T>(rhs, rhs)` ... maybe it makes sense to have a constructor from a single T to a Vector2 with the same T in each dimension?

This would also allow you to define a single `operator*` and rely on implicit conversion for scalar values.

---

Overall this looks pretty good.